# Wordpress displaying php blog page

Tags: php, wordpress, static, blogs

I know you can create a static front page using the wordpress dashboard; however, I would like to create my custom static front page just by coding the `index.php` page how I like and then providing a link to the blog.

I tried doing this by linking to `blog.php`. However I just get met with a blank page that just contains html and body tags. Is there a way to create a static front page site and just link to the blog without using the dashboard?

I don't like how using the dashboard to create a page automatically puts a heading tag on your page. Also, I don't know how to link to just the blog page without including links to all the other pages using `<?php wp_list_pages( '&title_li=' ); ?>`

Comment: Create `front-page.php`, which if exists, it is used on your site's front page regardless of whether the 'Settings → Reading → "Your homepage displays"' option is set to "A static page" or "Your latest posts". See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#front-page-display And for linking to your blog page, you can use something like.. `<a href="<?php the_permalink( 123 ); ?>">Visit Blog</a>` where `123` is the page ID. (I'm assuming that the blog page is already using the `blog.php` template)

Comment: For a href="<?php the_permalink( 123 ); ?> do I replace the_permalink( 123 ); with the permalink, or is that a function that I use and just put the permalink inside the parenthesis? Also, how do I know its permalink if it's not a page that I created through the dashboard? Can you explain what you mean by "I'm assuming that the blog page is already using the blog.php template"? I have a page that I created called blog.php, but I didn't specify that it was a template anywhere.

Comment: Your solution worked. I created a front-page.php document. Then, I made a blog page and it uses index.php. The only thing was I had to use get_permalink in the anchor tag instead of the_permalink. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Not a problem. I'm glad it helped you. =)